# link rewrite in htaccess file for SSL connection

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I'm using a php book to build a ecommerce site. It gives instructions to rewrite the htaccess file so that the site uses an SSL connection on certain pages. This is the code it gives.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that I'm using a shared server with a shared SSL certificate. So my url

```
https://.example.com/checkout.php
```

actually needs to be

```
https://example.c8.hostexcellence.com/checkout.php
```

but I can't figure out how to incorporate the `.c8.hostexcellence` into the rewrite so that it connects via SSL

Note, I tried the both of the following but they didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://example.c8.hostexcellence.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{example.c8.hostexcellence.com}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE

This is how it's supposed to be accessed with an SSL connection. I need to change my htaccess file so the links are established this way.

https://titanicraisins.c8.hostexcellence.com/checkout.php?session=72cac503b52a73308af0508fe462090a

This is my current htaccess file

AddHandler phpini-cgi .php .htm 
Action phpini-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-custom-ini.cgi

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# For sales:
RewriteRule ^shop/sales/?$ sales.php
# For the primary categories:
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z\+]+)/?$ shop.php?type=$1
# For specific products:
RewriteRule ^browse/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([A-Za-z\+\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ browse.php?type=$1&category=$2&id=$3
# For HTTPS pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `%{...}` around and just specify domain name

```
RewriteRule ^(checkout\.php|billing\.php|final\.php|admin/(.*))$ https://example.c8.hostexcellence.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: If you see at the bottom of my OP, I actually tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Michael: `RewriteRule . https://gmail.com` --- this trivial rule works for me. So explain in details then what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't set up the url as it should in the address bar. It leaves out ".c8.hostexcellence.", so no secure connection is made.   You can see for yourself at www.titanicraisins.com Click on the coffee link, and then select a coffee and then hit checkout.

Comment: @Michael: obviously you have wrong rule, and the issue has nothing to do with ssl. Put your complete .htaccess in the question and complete sample url.

Comment: @zerkms I updated my OP with my htaccess file and also a link given to me by the hostprovider showing how a secure link is supposed to be.

Comment: @Zerkms I'm assuming that the htaccess file is the only place in my application where the link has to be changed. For example, in my application files, I have links to http://titanicraisins.com/checkout.php If a user clicks on that link, then I'm assuming the htaccess file will rewrite it for the https connection, or do the links in the application have to be written differently?

Comment: @Michael: your rule works on my server. It redirects to `https` subdomain :-S

Comment: @zerkms did you click the link in the OP given to me by my hostprovider? or one from the actual site?  i had changed  the htaccess file back to the original given in the book so i don't see how it could redirect because it doesn't include c8.hostexcellence  plEASE TRy AGAIn

Comment: @zerkms o sorry, you said it works on your server. I thought you got it to work on mine. Hmm